# Microsoft Translator APIで401000認証エラーになる

Tags: curl

MACのターミナルで以下のコードを入力したところ、エラーが発生してしまいます。

Microsoft AzureではMarketplace内にあるTranslatorのところのみ設定して、キーとエンドポイント欄にあるキーをOcp-Apim-Subscription-Keyに入力しています。

他に設定する箇所があるのでしょうか？

設定後時間が経過しないと使えるようにならないのでしょうか？

この問題がクリアできたら、Pythonのプログラムで使いたいと思っています。

よろしくお願いします。

---

#### 実行したコマンド

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=zh-Hans" \
    -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: 88daf33*****" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
    -d "[{'Text':'Hello, what is your name?'}]"
```

#### エラーメッセージ

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":401000,
    "message":"The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

以下の引数でリージョン指定をすることで解決しました。
（公式参考にしたのですが私もつまづきました）

`-H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region:eastasia"`

**修正後のコマンド**

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&from=en&to=zh-Hans" \
    -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region:eastasia" \
    -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: *********" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
    -d "[{'Text':'Hello, what is your name?'}]"
```

**参考**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61573396/translator-text-api-microsoft-azure-always-error-401000